# Collection_select within a nested model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Timesheet model, a Run model, and an Athlete model.

```
class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :runs, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :runs
end


class Run < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :timesheet
  belongs_to :athlete
end

class Athlete < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :runs
end
```

Runs are nested under Timesheets, and I want to create a few runs on the same form I create a Timesheet, as shown in this [railscast](http://media.railscasts.com/videos/196_nested_model_form_part_1.mov)

```
class TimesheetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @timesheet = Timesheet.new
    3.times { @timesheet.runs.build }
  end
```

On my Timesheet form, I'm experiencing a problem with my collection_select (a drop down of Athlete names which populates the :athlete_id field in the Runs table).

```
<% form_for(@timesheet) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.label "Date" %>
  <%= f.text_field :date %>

  <% f.fields_for :runs do |builder| %>
    <%= collection_select(:run, :athlete_id, Athlete.all(:order => 'name'), :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select Athlete' } ) %>
  <% end %>

<%= f.submit 'Create' %>

<% end %>
```

Is it possible to populate the :athlete_id field of a Run with a collection_select as shown above, within a nested form for Timesheet, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you're not creating the collection select on the form builder, try something like this:

```
<% f.fields_for :runs do |r| %>
  <%= r.collection_select(:athlete_id, Athlete.all(:order => 'name'), :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select Athlete' } ) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly and saved me so much frustration.

Comment: I get an `undefined method name` error when I try this